# Creaking noise - from the cassette?

Tags: cassette, creak

I have a creaking noise when I pedal. Pretty sure it's coming from the cassette. I took my bike to the LBS and they said my chain was worn and that I also needed to replace my cassette. Cool, so I purchased a new chain and cassette. Today, I went to check my old cassette on the bike and I moved it and there was a play in the cassette.

It's a Shimano 105 5800 11 Speed Cassette, 11-28T.

It demonstrates 1/2mm play.

I just want to know if the creaking noise is coming from the cassette?

Comment: Can you post a short video of the problem?  We currently don't have enough information to give a decent answer.

Comment: How many gears are on the cassette? What is the range (number of teeth on the small gear and number of teeth on the large gear)?  What brand and model is the cassette?  This information and other can help give clues to arrive at a solution.  And as Criggie mentioned, what is your question?  How to get the noise to stop? Or why is there play in my cassette?

Answer (score 3):

The cassette-freehub interface is a sliding joint that is held on by the cassette locknut.  There is the possibility of movement under load because its a high torque location, and any slop in the fit can cause noise and losses.

You'd feel rotation and/or lateral play in the cogs, and if they're not one unit then they may move relative to each other too.

0.5mm or 1~2mm of play sideways suggests you might be missing a spacer.

If that motion is rotational then the freehub spline interface with the cassette is worn.